# Posting in Facebook page Shop issue

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

This code i used for post in fb page  shop.

when i am trying to save and post on fb give me 404 error and not posting in page shop
also maybe i am getting difficulties to get shop page id

```
final public function store(StoreProductPhotoRequest $request, int $id): JsonResponse
    {
        if ($request->has('photos')) {
            $product = (new Product())->getProductById($id);
            if ($product) {
                $fb = new Facebook([
                    'app_id' => 'app_id',
                    'app_secret' => 'app_secret',
                    'default_graph_version' => 'v17.0',
                ]);

                foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
                    $name = Str::slug($product->slug . '-' . Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString() . '-' . random_int(10000,99999));
                    $photo_data['product_id'] = $id;
                    $photo_data['is_primary'] = $photo['is_primary'];
                    $photo_data['photo'] = ImageUploadManager::processImageUpload(
                        $photo['photo'],
                        $name,
                        ProductPhoto::PHOTO_UPLOAD_PATH,
                        ProductPhoto::PHOTO_WIDTH,
                        ProductPhoto::PHOTO_HEIGHT,
                        ProductPhoto::THUMB_PHOTO_UPLOAD_PATH,
                        ProductPhoto::PHOTO_THUMB_WIDTH,
                        ProductPhoto::PHOTO_THUMB_HEIGHT,
                    );

                    (new ProductPhoto())->storeProductPhoto($photo_data);
                    $this->publishOnFacebookShop($product, $photo_data['photo'], $fb);
                }
            }
        }
        return response()->json(['msg' => 'Photo Added Successfully', 'cls' => 'success']);
    }

    private function publishOnFacebookShop($product, $photoUrl, $fb)
    {
        $accessToken = 'page_access_token;

        try {
            $response = $fb->post(
                '/page_shop_id/products',
                [
                    'name' => $product->name,
                    'description' => $product->description,
                    'image_url' => $photoUrl,
                    'price' => $product->price,
                    'currency' => 'BDT',
                    'availability' => 'in_stock',
                    'condition' => 'new',
                    'brand' => 'Hometex Bangladesh',
                    'url' => $product->url,
                ],
                $accessToken
            );

            $graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();
            $productId = $graphNode['id'];

        } catch (FacebookResponseException $e) {
            error_log('Facebook API Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        } catch (FacebookSDKException $e) {
            error_log('Facebook SDK Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```